# Checking continuity of functions defined by infinite series.

Tags: real-analysis

Which of the following functions are continuous?

(a) $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}, x\in\mathbb{R}$

(b)$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\cos nx}{n^{3/2}},x\in[-\pi,\pi]$

(c) $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2x^n,x\in[-1/2,1/2]$

Here is my attempt:

(a) Consider the partial sum of the series, $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}=\frac{x^2\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)^n\right)}{1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}=(1+x^2)\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)^n\right)=\begin{cases}0&x=0,\\non -zero&otherwise.\end{cases}$

Since the pertial sum of the series is not continuous
So option (a) is not continous.

(b) Since the given series is uniformly converget in compact set, so continuous as well.

(c) Partial sum of the series is nothing but polynomial so continuous thus the series is continuous.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of the first geometric series is $1+x^{2}$ for all $x\neq 0$ and $0$ for $x =0$ so $f$ is not continuous. Non-zero for $x \neq 0$ does not prove that $f$ is dis-continuous

Your answer for the second series is correct.

Partial sums being continuous does not imply that then infinite sum is continuous. The function c) is continuous because the series converges uniformly: The series $\sum \frac {n^{2}} {2^{n}}$ is convergent and we can apply M-Test to prove uniform convergence.

Comment: For the last option you replaced $x$ by $1/2$. Can we do this always for compact interval?

Comment: The series is dominated by the series $\sum \frac {n^{2}} {2^{n}}$ so we can apply M-Test. @JohnInfinity

Comment: For a): for $x=0$, the sum is $0$ so $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: @Koro Thanks for the correction.